# How to configure the parameters for deploying a project in different environments of SQL server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis, sql-server-2012, mssql-jdbc

I am an oracle developer, working first time with SQL servers.

I have created a project in SSIS which have 5 different packages in it, I have to deploy it in dedicated SQL servers(test, acceptance and Prod). where the variable values should be picked from the parameters which I have defined for my dedicated package on environment basis.

I read it in SQL tutorial that I have to convert my project to project deployment model which I have already done(2 packages failed because of some connection issues hence ignoring those 2 packages and focusing on other 3 packages inside the project).

I deployed it in my SQL server(test) but when trying to execute the package it fails stating "Error in reading source file".

Note : When I run the same package in local machine it runs but as soon as deploying to server it stops reading file.

I have created parameters under 1 package.

I am not sure, If I have to convert it to project deployment model or Legacy package deployment model.

Also read in tutorials and not understanding when to convert the project to Project deployment model and when to convert it to legacy package deployment model.

Comment: When you were running your package to local machine it was using your local account. Once you deploy the package to server, it uses the service account so you need to grant your service account access to the source file.

Comment: When I deploy it without parameters, I suppose it uses the same user(Service account) to read the source files and it works. When I deploy my project with parameters, it stops reading the file and throws error.

Comment: Can you share your parameters?